# I am stuck at the Specific odd even issue

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get that in php? I lost 2 days trying to solve this. plese help
Description image is here...
[image: Image description]

Here is my code. I realy dont know how to solve this.

```
<?php /*----------------------- predelava --------------------------*/ ?>

<?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=7&showposts=5'); //'cat=1 <-- Tukaj vpiši id tvoje kategorije ?>
<?php $numposts = $wp_query->post_count; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class='<?php echo (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'evenpost' : 'oddpost'; ?>'>
<?php if ($j != $numposts){
    the_content();
    }
?>

</div>

<?php if($numposts %2 == 0 && $j == $numposts)
    {
?>

<div class="center">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php // class "center" definiraj v css fajlu tako da bo pozicioniran kot želiš ;)
    }
    ?>

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php $wp_query = $temp_query; ?>
```

I tried also this way:

```
<?php
/*----------------------- predelava --------------------------*/
 $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=7&showposts=5'); //'cat=1 <-- Tukaj vpiši id tvoje kategorije ?>
<?php $numposts = $wp_query->post_count; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class='<?php echo (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'evenpost' : 'oddpost'; ?>'>
  <?php if ($j != $numposts){
      the_content();
      }  ?></div>

  <?php  if($numposts %2 != 0 && $j == $numposts)
    {
      ?><div class="center"><?php the_content(); ?></div>  <?php // class "center" definiraj v css fajlu tako da bo pozicioniran kot želiš ;)
    }
    ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $wp_query = $temp_query; ?>

</div>
```

Best regards from Slovenia

Comment: Are you literally trying to echo a `|` character? If not could you post example output of what you actually want?

Comment: And where does the while loop start?

Comment: I uploaded image with description, this is how it looks now: http://vezica.panorama360.org

Comment: Why do you put `<?php` on every line of the script, it makes it really hard to read.

Comment: I messed things up trying to make it work. Even in school i didnt like php :D and now i have problem...

Comment: Is ayone able to solve this? Best regards

Answer (score 0):

My friend helped me out :)

he did it this way:

```html
<?php
/*----------------------- predelava --------------------------*/

 $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=7&showposts=5'); //'cat=1 <-- Tukaj vpiši id tvoje kategorije ?>
<?php $numposts = $wp_query->post_count; ?>
<?php
$i = 1;
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

 
 if($i %2 != 0) 
 {
  if($i == $numposts)
  {
  echo "<div class='center'>";
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
  }else
  {
  echo "<div class='evenpost'>";
   the_content();
  echo '</div>';
  }
 }
 else
 {

  echo "<div class='evenpost'>";
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
  
 }
 $i++;
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $wp_query = $temp_query; ?>
```

Now it's working as it should. Thanks